# What do I do to change the my profile on facebook, not sent to my friends?

Tags: facebook

I don't like when I change my profile (For example, when I change my profile picture) anyone noticed. pleas help me and show me a way.

Comment: I don't understand the question here? Do you want to keep any changes to your profile secret?

Comment: no, I don' want anybody to see my Activities

Answer (score 2):

You can control the visibility of each post you make.

Next to the "Post" button there's a drop down which changes the visibility of that post:

[image]

For more information see the help page on [privacy settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy):

> Your selection sticks around for your next post until you change it — either online when you post or here [on the privacy page]:

Comment: I don't believe this is what he means. He means actions such as editing Favorite Quotations or changing his profile picture, not posts.

Comment: @ekaj - you might be right. However, until the OP comes back and comments I'll leave this up here.